# Can't load ios third party keyboard without full access

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm developing an iOS keyboard extension, it works well when full access enable at the first time.
But can't load when full access disabled on first time.
Does anyone know why?

I've trusted the provider's profile.

Answer (score 0):

third party keyboard works without `full access` but it depends on code you have written, for example i have stored data in custom shared container and with ID-s i can retrieve them and re-create as `UIImage` but if i have no full access enabled then i have issues like this: `NSUserDefaults` are not saving data to shared app group, cant play sounds (in iOS 9 you can), cant use `UIPasteBoard` for pasting something.